# JQuery plugin submethods

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am having some problems undestanding how to make "subfunctions" in a JQuery plugin.
What i would like to achieve is somehting like the following

```
var tags = $('#tagContainer').ImageTags({ option1: "blah blah", option1: "blah blah", option1: "blah blah"});
tags.ShowTagAdd(someIdHere, someOtherId);
```

The reason for this is that some times i need to force show my TagAdd dialog on page load, i can do this via options, but i would like to keep it more clean :D Here is my code so far, it is written in TypeScript but it should be readable as normal JQuery :D

I basicly just wonna run my method `ShowTag(categoryid: number, characterId: number)` when the subfunction is called, how can i do this?

```
    module ImageModule {
    export interface DefaultOptions {
        ImageId: number;
    }

    export class ImageTags {
        defaults: DefaultOptions = {
            ImageId: 0,
        };
        options: DefaultOptions;
        TagsContainer: JQuery;

        constructor(element: JQuery, options: DefaultOptions) {
            this.options = <DefaultOptions> $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
            this.TagsContainer = element;
            var self = this;

        }


        ShowTag(categoryid: number, characterId: number) {
            console.log("test");
        }
    }

    $.fn["ImageTags"] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_ImageTags")) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_ImageTags", new ImageTags($(this), options));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to archive this is:

```
$.fn.ImageTags = function(...) {

    return {
        ShowTagAdd: function(...) {

        }
    };

};
```

Since is returning an object with the method, you can do it just the way you want, but this breaks the jQuery chainability philosophy.

It'll be better like:

```
(function($, undefined){

    $.fn.ImageTags = function(options) {

        var pluginName = 'ImageTags';
        var plugin = $(this).data(pluginName);

        if(plugin) {

            return plugin;

        } else {

            var settings = $.extend({}, options);

            return this.each(function() {

                var widget = $(this);

                var ShowTagAdd = function(...) {};

                var api = {
                    ShowTagAdd: ShowTagAdd
                };

                widget.data(pluginName, api);

            });

        }

    }

})(jQuery);
```

So you can define your methods as "private" and expose the ones you like in the api:

```
tags.ImageTags().ShowTagAdd(...);
```

or

```
tags.data('ImageTags').ShowTagAdd(...);
```

The great thing of using closures is that you can have some private methods.

There are other ways but I don't have time right now!

Comment: Thank you, in your example where will i load my "main" class, ImageTags? would it be something like `var c = new ImageTags($(this), options); var ShowTagAdd = c.ShowTag; var api ....`

Comment: ok, take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/coma/tEaDM/1/ and check some plugins out there, like https://github.com/coma/jquery.select